# How can I make a town with my friends, without strangers?

Tags: the-trail

In "The Trail" it seems the social aspect is the community building of our wild west town.

But you get bunched up with some random strangers that may not be as active as one would wish (or not at all).

Several of my friends began playing, and I'd very much like to be in the same town as them.

Is there a way to make a town with your friends / pick your neighbors?